# Selenium python removed header and footer from page source need to get text

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Chrome Path
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.sap.com/about/events/2021-05-25-online-pe-payment-processing-sap.html")
element = driver.page_source
remove_header = element.split("</header>")
remove_header_footer = remove_header[1].split("<footer>")
```

This will remove header and footer from `driver.page_source` . Is there any solution that I can get text from remaining part of HTML source. (Only the text)

Answer (score 0):

When we do `driver.page_source` it returns a **string**

```
remove_header_footer
```

is basically a **sub string** of `page_source` so doing `.text` on that does not make any sense, does it ?

Instead use this :

```
print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//html[not(contains(@id, 'header')) and not(contains(@id, 'footer'))]").text)
```

I got **output** like this :

```
> Products Industries Services and Support Training Community Partner
> About COVID-19 Try & Buy Payment Processing for SAP May 25, 2021
> Online - Live Register Now Event Overview In this day and age,
> accepting electronic payments, like credit card and ACH/eCheck, is
> more important than ever before. Not only do electronic payments
> increase customer convenience, they also benefit the merchant by
> encouraging timely payments from customers and increasing cash flow.
> Join EVO Payments and SAP as we discuss implementing payment
> processing directly into your SAP platform. Who should attend:
> Companies looking to integrate payment processing into any of the
> following SAP platforms: SAP S/4HANA SAP S/4HANA Cloud SAP S/4HANA
> Cloud for Customer Payments SAP Commerce Cloud SAP Subscription
> Billing ERP Central Component (ECC) PayFabric from EVO Payments
> PayFabric is a simple, flexible and secure payment processing platform
> that enables businesses of all sizes to accept electronic payments.
> With PayFabric, merchants can reduce PCI compliance, automate manual
> accounts receivables tasks, and save on credit card processing rates.
> Event Category SAP Event Event Type Online - Live Language English
> Industry Industrial Machinery and Components, Life Sciences, Mining,
> Mill Products, Media, Utilities, Aerospace and Defense, Public Sector,
> Professional Services, Telecommunications, Oil and Gas, Engineering,
> Construction, and Operations, Chemicals, High Tech, Automotive,
> Retail, Consumer Products, Sports and Entertainment, Travel and
> Transportation, Banking, Higher Education and Research, Defense and
> Security, Insurance, Healthcare, Wholesale Distribution Intended
> Audience SAP Users Featured Speaker(s) Rachael Brancich (EVO) and SAP
> Phone Number
> +909-482-4701 Location United States Take Action E-Mail Register Now How is your experience with this page? Quick Links Why SAP Intelligent
> Enterprise Small and Midsize Enterprises SAP Trust Center SAP Insights
> SAP Community Developer Support Portal About SAP Company Information
> Worldwide Directory Investor Relations Careers News and Press Events
> Customer Stories Newsletter Site Information Privacy Terms of Use
> Legal Disclosure Copyright Trademark Sitemap Text View Cookie
> Preferences Find us on
```